# Detecting href click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I have been trying for a few days now to figure out how to detect a user click, and assign new properties to a variable. I have attempted this in a few different ways most of them however not working.

So far I have this, which is pretty self explainitory.

```
var settings = {
    objSlideTrigger: '#one', // link button id
    objSlidePanel: '#content-one' // slide div class or id       
};


if(document.getElementById('#one').click) {
 var setup = settings;
    setup.objSlideTrigger = '#one',
    setup.objSlidePanel = '#content-one'
};

if(document.getElementById('#two').click) {
 var setup = settings;
    setup.objSlideTrigger = '#two',
    setup.objSlidePanel = '#content-two'
};
```

when the user clicks a href on the page it I want it to be detected by the javascript and, for the correct setup to be placed within the settings var for use by the rest of the code.
 I have two questions really the first being, I will have to duplicate the conditional statement at least ten times so is there anyway to condense/simplify the code.

secondly,When detecting a Href click in javascript do i have to assign an onclick value to the actual element in the html?

thanks again.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){}` then you use `document.getElmentById('').click`? :o

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Forgot to remove it, when i was editing.

Comment: Do you mean <a> elements by saying hrefs? One can not click hrefs, one can click an <a> (anchor) element which has an href attribute

Comment: Your edit was weird, are you using jQUery or pure JavaScript?

Comment: Yes i mean A 'anchor tags', I refer to them as hrefs.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's .on() function? Something like, $(

Comment: I am using javascript, But im open to alternative solutions.

Comment: Why are you tagging jQuery then? Pure JS?

Comment: Because I have been browing the web for 5 days editing and cutting snippets of code trying to find a solution to my problem. Im not all that farmiliar with Js or Jquery so it is possible I may have cut it in. incorrectly. The orginal code snippet is jquery, but I assument they would work together. as the languages seem the tame to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### With jQuery

Assuming you're wanting to use jQuery because you've included it at the top, use:

```
$(document).on('click', '#one', function( event ) {
   //Do Code here
   //For #one click event
});
```

Although, to prevent DRY - keep it more generic by using Classes:

```
<div class="updatesettings" id="one">One</a>
<div class="updatesettings" id="two">Two</a>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.updatesettings', function( event ) {
       //Do Code here
       //For all .updatesettings click event
       alert( $(this).attr('id') );
    });
</script>
```

### With JavaScript

```
var OnOneClick = function() { 
  // Your click handler
};

var OneClick = document.getElementsById("#one");
OneClick.addEventListener('click', OnOneClick, false);
```

Then to listen for multiple, use by Class (Although not all IE versions can listen for this):

```
var AwaitedClickEvent = function() {
    //Class Click
}

var WaitingClick = document.getElementsByClassName('clickme');
for (var i = 0; i < WaitingClick.length; i++) {
   var current = WaitingClick[i];
   current.addEventListener('click', AwaitedClickEvent, false);
}
```

### Your Solution

```
<!-- Links with ID & Content -->
<div class="updatesettings" id="one" data-content="content-one">One</a>
<div class="updatesettings" id="two" data-content="content-two">Two</a>

<script>
    /**
     *   Get the clicked element's ID
     *   and it's stored data-content string.
    **/
    $('.updatesettings').on('click', function( event ) {
         var Id = $(this).attr('id'),
             Content = $(this).data('content'),
             setup = settings,
             setup.objSlideTrigger = Id,
             setup.objSlidePenl = Content;

         console.log( setup );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is not quite what was asked for, there are several elements probably like #one, #two, .. #ten and there shall not be 10 click handlers for each

Comment: "I will have to duplicate the conditional statement at least ten times so is there anyway to condense/simplify the code"

Comment: Beaniie seriously, say if you work with jquery or not. Creating code for jquery is way easier so dont play with that please!

Comment: The jquery solution is detecting the click of the divs? and not the links? The divs are hidden off screen.

Comment: I have just said alex in the answer above, the original snippet is jquery, but as im not all to farmiliar with js or jquery, i assumed they would work together. I now know this is not the case. Im now workign with jquery only.

Comment: @Beaniie select this answer as best answer on the left side green tick if it solved your question.

Comment: @Beaniie jQuery **is** JavaScript, so you can use both together. There are just certain things you have to account for, such as not trying to access native element properties on a jQuery object. You can't do, for example, `$('#checked').checked` to see if a checkbox element with an ID of checked is in fact checked.

Comment: I will do, Thanks for your input guys. You have explained why ive been getting nowhere for the past 5-6 days... :)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ahh I see.

Comment: Just onething to clear up... <div class="updatesettings" id="one" data-content="content-one">One</a> is it a div or an achor?

Comment: I've used a `<div>` because `<div>`'s don't have an expected browser behaviour, unlike `<a>` are __expected__ to take you to another page, thus you'd have to prevent that with JavaScript. Using a `<div>` or an `<span>` will allow you to have full control of what you want to do when you click it, for like your example - update `setup` variable.

Comment: I'm just not sure I understand how the script interacts between the two now. For example i have added a js fiddle that shows what i am trying to achieve, only i want to have multiple links and divs. http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/6/

Comment: @MackieeE Sorry if im not being much help.

Comment: YES precisely... Thank you. Its not needed but ill ask for future reference is there a way to make each panel close when another is opened?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/44/ Add it to the start of the click binder, look for any class with `'out'` class and tell it to go home =)